# How can I run sudo gedit as gksu gedit

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sudo, gedit

I'm looking into ways of automatically loading Gedit as `gksu gedit` when I enter `sudo gedit` by mistake?

I have found that I have made a number of files unreachable by using gedit and I have only just found out why!

**ACHIEVED SO FAR**

I have written a script which will make an `alias` so that if I type in `sudo <application>` it can automatically convert that to `gksu <application>` but I want to make this alias stick, so that I don't have to run the script every time I boot the computer.

Is there a config file I can edit or should I run this script as a start up script (which would be inconvenient!)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `.bashrc` file
`gedit ~/.bashrc`

Add following alias
`alias sudo='gksu'`

Now restart terminal to start using the alias.

Only add `alias gedit='gksu gedit'` if you want gksu only for `gedit`.
`echo 'alias gedit='gksu gedit' >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Brilliant, I just found the same answer after spending days searching in the wrong place :)

Comment: Add `alias gedit='gksu gedit'` if u want gksu only for gedit. (Remove the earlier)

Comment: it's good for `sudo nautilus`, `sudo dolphin` as well so I think I'll leave the original alias :)

Comment: I have updated to `alias gedit='gksu gedit'` as I had problems with sudo `apt-get autoremove` not completing

Answer (score 3):

You could make a smart function that will transform automatically `sudo` to `gksu` when the command following it is in a set of pre-programmed functions like so: in your `.bashrc` add:

```
sudo_to_gksu=( "gedit" "nautilus" )
sudo() {
    local sudo=$(which sudo)
    local f
    for f in "${sudo_to_gksu[@]}"; do
        if [[ $1 = $f ]]; then
            sudo=gksu
            break
        fi
    done
    "$sudo" "$@"
}
```

So when you type `sudo` followed by `gedit` or `nautilus`, it will automatically change the `sudo` to `gksu`, and otherwise it will leave the `sudo`. Add some more programs in the array `sudo_to_gksu` if you wish. You can also extend this to also have `gksudo` instead of `gksu` if you wish.

This might have some side effects... let me know if it's the case!

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'll try this out, it looks very flexible. Thank you