# A Weird GUI Problem With GNOME Programs

Tags: gnome, 18.04, screen, gui, gedit

My Ubuntu OS' version is 18.04.1 LTS.

When I start gedit, this is the result **gedit screenshot**:

[image]

Same problem arises with **GNOME Calculator**:

[image]

I think some things wrong with GNOME programs. I wish to know followings:

- Why is this happening?
- How can i fix this?

Comment: *GNOME. Those aren't GNU programs.

Comment: What kind of graphics card do you have?

Comment: My laptop have two graphic card. Hd graphics and nvidia. I am using bumblebee.

Answer (score 5):

You could experience a problem related to input method modules.
(https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1760818)

Try starting e.g. gedit by disabling GTK_IM_MODULE

```
GTK_IM_MODULE=none gedit
```

and check whether the issue is gone.

If it is gone, you could try to set GTK_IM_MODULE to none by invoking

```
im-config
```

and selecting choice "none" in the dialogs.

A reboot is necessary, afterwards.

Comment: This fixed my problem. When I set it back to IBus and rebooted, the problem was still fixed. This answer should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: I have the same issue when using gnome-calculator and gedit. This answer fixes the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Install the 'Synaptic Package Manager' and search for `gedit`,

using:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

This will help to figure out what is going on with any program/package issues.

Comment: I don't understand how can I use synaptic package manager to solve the problem.

Comment: Did you install it and try to search gedit ?     .............It's self explanatory, if there is a problem synaptic will indicate if there is a problem with the install, ie: broken package, unmet dependencies, wrong version etc .....

Comment: I am using synaptic already. But it doesn't indicate anything. Everything seems normal.

Comment: Hmmm. I don't know what the problem could be. The only suggestion I have is to open synaptic, search gedit, right click and choose 'mark for complete removal', click apply and after it completes, right click and 'mark for installation' then after the reinstall click on the 'reload' icon, then click the 'mark all upgrades' ...follow through if there are any upgrades. Click on the 'apply' icon and that's it. If that doesn't fix it, then it's above my pay-grade.

Comment: Also take a look at these links: https://snapcraft.io/gedit  .......https://snapcraft.io/gnome-calculator

Comment: Unfortunately didn't solve.

Answer (score 1):

By the way - your calculator may be a 'snap' program.

Try: `sudo snap install gnome-calculator`

Try: `sudo snap refresh`

Comment: I have tried already but not working. And also problem is not special to calculator. The exact same thing happens to also gedit.

Answer (score 0):

This link may be of help:

[gedit not working? [duplicate]](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/7551/gedit-not-working)

Using: `apt-get install --reinstall gedit` must have space before the `--reinstall`

or:

```
sudo apt-get purge gedit && sudo apt-get install gedit
```

Also [try](https://askubuntu.com/questions/579085/gedit-not-working-even-though-its-installed-in-ubuntu-14-10):

```
sudo apt-get purge gedit gedit-common
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install gedit
```

And do it for the [Gnome calculator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039411/how-can-i-replace-snap-application-such-as-gnome-calculator-with-a-deb):

```
sudo snap remove gnome-calculator
```

and enter the following to install the deb version:

```
sudo apt install gnome-calculator
```

Another possibly is to update the 18.04.1 OS system with:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -f
```

Comment: I have had tried but it is not working. And also problem is not special to gedit.

Comment: Can you open gedit from the ubuntu search icon for "gedit", i.e. without using terminal?

Comment: It is not also working.

Comment: I have tried your last edit but not working.

Comment: Restart the computer?

Comment: I did a lot of times.

Comment: What is not working? the command `sudo dpkg --configure -a` etc. or the `gedit` part?

Comment: any of them not working.

Comment: Have you tried this one? --> [Can't open terminal in Ubuntu 18.04 after upgrade from 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040566/cant-open-terminal-in-ubuntu-18-04-after-upgrade-from-17-10)

Comment: Sorry, I am not a native English speaker and I think I have used wrong words. I have no problem with terminal. By "working", I meant any of the solutions you recommended didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Okay! Here's another one to try: [Terminal not working on Ubuntu 18.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1788364) . It's good to try it, even if it appears unrelated, it could solve it. @luis-de-sousa "for those seeking for a solution to this: removing the orca package permanently solves this issue: `sudo apt purge orca`  "

Comment: It didn't solve.

Comment: I just tried `synaptic`. I think you need to find out what it tells you about `gedit`. Ask **@Better Ideas** what to look for. Have you just recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 ?

Comment: Try these ones: [gedit not opening from terminal - not authenticated](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/gedit-not-opening-from-terminal-not-authenticated-4175530980/) and [gedit fails to open as root in terminal](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=154120)

Comment: Also see: [How can I run sudo gedit as gksu gedit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314938/how-can-i-run-sudo-gedit-as-gksu-gedit). Try `sudo gedit`  ?

Comment: In synaptic everything seems normal. Unfortunately they didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I suggest saving all your important files to storage device (e.g. USB stick). Once you have backed up your files, you could try to reinstall ubuntu 18.04.1. If that doesn't work, try installing 16.04 LTS. You could, however, first test if `gedit` works on your ubuntu 18.04.1, by booting it from the original USB drive containing the OS? I.e. boot 18.04.1 from the USB stick and try `gedit` there. To test if it is the OS or the hard drive. If it is the OS, then download a new one and install.